# Update on technical differences between C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have searched for these and can only find posts on 2008 or earlier?

I have my own list, but I want to know if there are more?

- Vb.NET doesn't support implicit interfaces (this really is annoying:()
- Vb.NET doesn't support another setter protection than the getter on automatic properties
- Vb.NET doesn't support Preprocessor Directives
- Vb.NET doesn't support Arithmetic Overflow unchecking/checking in code
- Vb.NET doesn't support the yield keyword (iterator blocks)
- Vb.NET doesn't support execution of unsafe (i.e. pointer-based) operations.

And then we have the support for the environments like type coloring which is still poor in vs.net 2010 and not full support from resharper and so on but that is not any technical aspect.
Have i missed something?, I have heard that there could be some differences in linq querying is that true?

Comment: Perhaps see the list of dups from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866117/what-things-can-you-do-in-vb-net-and-not-in-c

Answer (score 2):

C# *still* doesn't have exception filters...

- [Try...Catch...Finally Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement)
- [Catch, Rethrow and Filters - Why you should care?](https://web.archive.org/web/20100805065211/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/clrteam/archive/2009/02/05/catch-rethrow-and-filters-why-you-should-care.aspx)

Comment: @annakata: Exceptions should only be caught if the code which is catching them has some likelihood of *resolving* them.  While exception filters can be dangerous, they help make it possible to avoid the catch-and-rethrow anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Multiline string literal with @ in C# is missing in VB.NET. Makes long strings really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Probably lots more, but in my day to day work these are the ones that annoy me the most (I can't abide VB.Net):

VB.Net has optional parameters, C# does not.
C# has a mechanism to generate XML documentation from code tags.
C# has the **using** keyword
C# allows you to write unsafe (eg pointer-related) code.

hth.

Comment: C# has optional parameters now.

Comment: Are you sure about the *unmanaged* code part?  Isn't that only in C++.Net?

Comment: VB has the `Using` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx

Comment: @Johann Strydom unsafe code in c#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Making a component that can be called from COM is very easy in VB.Net.  In C# it is almost impossible.

Comment: To all the people who have down voted me: Have you even tried doing it?

Comment: No vote from me, -2 is about enough.  But, yes, it is trivial.  Mostly because it is done the *exact same way*.  Maybe you ought to ask a question about it...

Comment: OK I get the message.  Perhaps this has improved since I tried it in VS2005.